# OpenCV circles grid calibration

Tags: calibration, opencv, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I was wondering if anyone has had experience with the new [OpenCV circles grid](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV%20Change%20Logs) calibration pattern.  Any better results?  Any worse results?  Sad that your beautiful metal checkerboards are obsolete?  :P

If it proves promising, we should probably update the camera_calibration package to support it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10750/opencv-circles-grid-calibration/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-07-27**:
I think it can eventually have a succinct answer.  Eventually we'll have a preferred method of calibration or at least circumstances.  The question really is: which is better?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-27**:
This is probably a better question for the mailing list since it doesn't have a succinct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The blob detector is indeed more robust to noise than the corner one and we experimented better results with it.

Adding it to the camera_calibration package is on the agenda but there is not timeline yet.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-11-18**:
Is this already added in the experimental branch?